# How to convert people picker value to username using SPServices

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, spservices

I have a **people picker column** in my list and the values when i **call** it via **SPServices** turns out to be

`#10; last, first(dept_num);#35; last2, first(dept_num)`

Is there a way to get a username from that?
I would like to do a `GetUserProfileByName`

Comment: Have you tried GetUserProfileByName? Just use the "last, first(dept_num)" as the name and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks, i ended up just changing the list settings for that specific people field to disply the domain/username instead of that last,name (dept). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 public String IsNULL(string strnull)
 {
     if (strnull == dval)
         return dval;
     else
          return Convert.ToString(strnull.Split('#')[1]);
 }
```

Pass your string to this function. It will remove the id of group and gives you exact group name.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to mentioned via SPServices in javascript.